# How to make my embedded mp4 video code in google chrome because it is working in safari?

Tags: video

I have a mp4 video embedded in my website kreatiewe.com. It plays in safari but not google chrome on my desktop. I will play in google chrome on my mobile.

I have had a few developers look into this and none can figure it out. I have compressed file and tried different ones with the same results.

```
<div class="slider__item">
<div class="slider__iframe__wrapper">
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline id="myVideo">
<source src="images/photos/liquid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
<div class="slider__video_darcken"></div>
    <div class="container">
<div class="slider__wrapper">
<span class="item__text">We are a creative team since 2010</span>
<h1 class="item__text item__text_big">We make websites, interfaces and identity.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like video to play in all browsers. If video wont play is the code to just show image for those that it wont play in?

Comment: can you point us to a live sample that shows the problem (either the website, a staging site, or a JSfiddle)

Comment: Website is kreatiewe.com Don't use www.kreatiewe.com it will take will not work.

Comment: look at error in dev tools | console ... looks like it is running the script before the slider div is available